# OpenID connect implicit flow response

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Between the Authorization Request (3.1.2.1) and the Authentication Response (3.1.2.5) the authorization server is responsible for validating the request, authenticating the user, and get user-consent before sending the response.

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth

How is that supposed to work in a SPA application?

If I issue an ajax request the authorization server can't authenticate the user (I don't see how since there's no cookie, http-header or url fragment telling the Authorization Server who the user is). If I redirect the user to the authentication endpoint my SPA is unloaded. Since I don't have a server redirect_uri (which I've understood is the whole point of the implicit flow?) the endpoint can never reach my SPA again.

Obviously I'm missing something. How is the authentication and user-authorization chrome supposed to be shown to the user in the implicit flow?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect separate the authentication from the application. You would redirect unauthenticated clients/users away from your application before anything is loaded and only handle the authorization response in the SPA. Your redirect URI would point to the SPA. In any case, you would not handle the OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect dance in Ajax but in a full browser.

Comment: Thanks, I found out I can use a popup and capture the response and return it to the SPA, that way my SPA is still loaded and can use the captured token. Maybe there's some way to capture the response with a full redirect too.

Comment: @Molotch is there a guide on how to capture the response in the popup and how to return it to the SPA?